# grafana code not showing up after version change from v10 to v8 in local

Tags: graph, version, prometheus, grafana, promql

i moved my grafana version from v10.1.0 to v8.5.6
as some queries were not functional in v10.1.0

i deleted the existing docker image of grafana and pulled in a new image with 8.5.6 version
and then set the docker up
i can use the builder option and the json file i saved earlier dashboard is showing me graphs that i had plotted before. But the code is showing loading and its not showing up

can anyone help on this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfSMf.png)

i was expecting i can write queries

Comment: All I can say is that downgrade over two major versions is not advised, and AFAIK, Grafana doesn't provide/support downgrades, so your best shot IMO is using backups from before the upgrade.